# working approach to merge multiple resource paths in Qt/webkit?

Tags: javascript, qt, resources, webkit

I'm writing an application that uses Qt/webkit to display documents.
They are XML based and XSLT is applied to the document to get final
representation in HTML.

Each document can refer to various resources:

1. System shared items in /usr/share/app/common
2. User-specific items in /home/user/.config/app/custom_styles
3. Document-specific items in /document/document_things

the document contains math which is processed by jsMath scripts,
which are located in system-shared area. There are also common
images and CSS styles.

Each user can ovveride parts of the document and has his own
settings in his home directory, for example css styles.

Finally, each document comes with it's own uniq resources,
what can be anything - videos, archives or scripts.

Application loads the document and knows 3 paths for each
of resources and passes them into XSLT to generate final
HTML which will be loaded into QWebView to be presented
for the user.

The issue is that I need to setup baseURL correctly for
the webview, which is really tricky:

scheme issues: windows and linux treat file:/// and simple '/' starting
URLS differently in different aspects, producing a mess in code (add
letters in path on windows)

also, I've just found that URL can't end in '/' with Qt 4.8.0 - with
this webkit produces security error, complaining about cross-site scripting.
I have to set various security settings in QWebSettings like 
LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls for things to work.

Such subtle things are really hard to debug and maintain especially when
you have cross-platforming in mind and a zoo of various qt/webkit versions
deployed everywhere (btw, 4.7 just segfaults on incorrect XSLT...)

So, the questions are:

1) What to use as base url for generated HTML considering that I need
to include multiple resources from various places and working JS ?

2) Is it worth to attempt to create 'virtual' directory combining all
resources using symlinks or something similar?
This would solve problem with base url, but I'm not sure if such
functionality is available on Windows and want to stay with Qt-only solution..

The issue becomes more complex, when I think about future - I'd like
to enable to load documents from web and still have user resources locally.

Any suggestions on how to deal with the mess ?